# Given a point on the surface of a sphere, how to find points at a given angle?

Tags: geometry

I have a sphere centered around the origin. I am given an random point $(x, y, z)$ that lies on the surface of the sphere.

I want to find the points on the surface of the sphere that at a certain degree from my original point.

For example, if we were to consider a circle instead of a sphere as seen below. I am given a point $B$. I want to find the 2 orange points that are at $45^\circ$ from point $B$ and point $A$.

[image: example]

Comment: Similar to [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4714957/89922).

Comment: If you work in spherical coordinates with the North Pole as the reference point, then these are exactly the lines of latitude. For instance, the 30-degree North line of latitude is the set of points on the sphere which are 60 degrees from the North Pole.

Comment: @Semiclassical I think that makes sense. How does the mathematical formula look like to calculate these coordinates?

Comment: Let $(a,b,c)$ be a required point, let $R$ be the radius of the sphere, then the dot product

$$(a,b,c)\cdot (x,y,z) = ax+by+cz = R^2\cos 45^\circ$$
would define a plane. The intersection of this plane and the sphere $a^2+b^2+c^2 = R^2$ is a circle.

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks. I am not sure if I fully understand, so an example would be helpful to go through. Let's say the equation of the sphere is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 25$ so the radius is 5.  The given point is (5, 0, 0). How do I determine the points at 45 degrees?

Comment: In this case, the plane would be $$\begin{align*}
(x,y,z)\cdot (5,0,0) &= 5^2\cos45^\circ\\
5x &= 5^2/\sqrt2\\
x &= 5/\sqrt2
\end{align*}$$
Then the $yz$ coordinates satisfy $y^2+z^2 = 25-x^2 = 25/2$, which obviously defines a circle.

Comment: I should not repost [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714957) but improve the previous one and ask for its reopening.

Comment: [Is it allowed to repost?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31573/386889)